# I want to use WP UI tab in my header.php

Tags: wordpress

I want to use WP Ui tab in header.php instead of any pages or post.in pages i can add like this:-

```
[wptabs mode="horizontal"] [wptabtitle] Map[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]map detail[/contentment][wptabtitle] Get Bids[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]bid detail[/wptabcontent] [/wptabs]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[wptabs mode="horizontal"] [wptabtitle][/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent][/contentment][wptabtitle][/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent][/wptabcontent] [/wptabs]'); ?>
```

You can use the do_shortcode function of wordpress for this purpose.. e-g add the above function in your header.php . If you are not programmer then i suggest you to take help from some professional developer.